# Is it thread safe to use more then one Stream.BeginWrite in parallel?

Tags: c#, stream

I have a file that im going to fill up so I tought if its better to do it simultaneously.

**Notes:**

1. I get the file from multiple computers simultaneously.
2. I set the position every time befor calling StartWrite. -> Do I must lock it each time befor using it?

Is it good sulotion? Do you have a better one?

btw, what does Stream.Flush() ?

Thanks.

Comment: wow... you're really looking for trouble ;)

Comment: you make it looks like I try to Break obama email.

Comment: Describe the problem better. How do you know to what position to set? How big are thing?  And Yes, you'd have to lock. So don't even try to use async.

Comment: each computer send me a part with start index, end index and byte[]. Anything else?

Comment: Only one thing can write to a file at a time.  Even if Stream.BeginWrite supported multiple threads writing at a time, you'd be blocked by the file system and end up reducing performance switching between blocked threads.

Comment: It might be a silly idea but why dont you get the file in chunks and then stich it up in the end

Comment: @PeterRitchie this is untrue. Why wouldn't it be possible to write to the same file concurrently? Databases do this all the time. (See my answer). What the OP is asking is not unreasonable.

Comment: @usr No, it's true.  You can have multiple write operations "occuring" at the same time. but the file system only allows each block to be written atomically.  e.g. there's only one head on an HD, it can only be asked to do one thing at a time--everything else is "queued".

Comment: @PeterRitchie now we are talking about physical device limitations, not software. (Think of SSDs or SANs or RAID, they operate truly concurrently. But that is not the point).

Comment: @usr well, we're limited by physical device limitations in what software can do.  Yes, you can call `BeginWrite` multiple times and effectively "queue" multiple writes but the underlying files ystem has a single pipe of instructions that it processes one at a time.  Sure, and SSD doesn't have a "head" and can possibly not abide by a per-head limitation; but it still mimicks a traditional HD on IDE/SATA--which has a single pipeline of requests (i.e. one at a time).

Comment: @PeterRitchie just not true. IOs can execute truly concurrently on certain hardware. Even desktop magnetic drives with NCQ reorder IOs in hardware. For that reason many disk benchmarks specify an IO queue depth > 1 (like 32). IOs really do run concurrently on the same OS, disk, file and even file handle. (Again: Ask the SQL Server guys).

Comment: @usr you can have overlapped IO and interleave your requests in a more efficient way, but the device still only operates on one thing at a time.

Comment: @usr SQL Server can use its own drivers to access other types of devices to do whatever it wants; but for the rest of us who are stuck with the BCL and the filesystem, we aren't able to support these other types of devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that would be conceptually wrong. Stream (I assume you mean a [System.IO.Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx) class) is an abstract class. When you instantiate an object you are using one of many child classes.

Assuming anything about child classes is wrong approach because:

a) Somebody might come after you to made modifications to your code and not see what actual child class implementation does. 
b) Less likely, but the implementation can change. For example, what if someone installs your code on Mono framework.

If you are using FileStream class, consider creating two (or more) FileStream objects over the same underlying file with [FileShare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx) parameter set to Write. This way you specify that there might be simultaneous writing, but each stream has its own location pointer.

Update: Only now I saw your comment "each computer send me a part with start index, end index and byte[]". Actually, multiple FileStreams should work OK for this scenario.

```
    void DataReceived(int start, byte[] data)
    {
        System.IO.FileStream f = new System.IO.FileStream("file.dat", System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Write, System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite);
        f.Seek(start, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
        f.Write(data, start, data.Length);
        f.Close();
    }
```

Comment: if you think its poossibol, can you write more about how I make it done? Any idea?

Comment: Well, whenever you receive a package from 'a computer', create a FileStream object as I described above, write into it at correct offset and then close the handle. You can do it in separate threads or separate applications, operating system will write to the same file independently.

Comment: at the button line, will it be in parallel or one at a time?

Comment: Check the code I just added to the answer: if this function is called from multiple threads (or even processes) it will be written OK. In the end, it really depends on the media you are writing to: a physical disc performs writing differently the SSD, but as far as .NET is concerned, this is in parallel.

Comment: wait, you mean to creat one filestream for each thread? its like [localThread]Position :P good idea.

Answer (score 2):

This is unsafe by principle because even if your stream was thread-safe you would still have to non-atomically set the position and write.

The native Windows file APIs support this, .NET doesn't. Windows is perfectly capable of concurrent IO to the same file (how would SQL Server work if Windows didn't support this?).

I suggest you just use one writing `FileStream` per thread.

Comment: You and zmilojko have same solution. Thank you too.

Answer (score 1):

It's pointless to try to do several write operations to the same stream at the same time.

The underlying system can only write to one position in the file at a time, so even if the asynchronous write method would support multi threading, the writes would still be blocked.

Just do regular writes to the file, and use locking so that only one thread at a time writes to the file.